# Once deployed, how do I figure out whether an app service is Windows or Linux?

Tags: azure, azureportal

I have an app service, but I can't see anywhere on the Azure Portal that shows whether it is Linux or Windows.

Where would I get this information?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Other way is to open the command line from the app service blade and type the command to get the version of OS, for ex,

[image]

Comment: both answers are good, but ill mark this one as best because this is unlikely to change anytime soon whereas Microsoft is always changing their azure portal aroudn

Answer (score 19):

You can go to the list of the App Service Plans in the portal and check if the plan hosting the app is Linux or Windows.

[image]

You can also go to Kudu(scm site) and if you see 'Debug Console' option it is a Windows app service. Where as for a Linux app, you would see Bash and SSH options.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Funny that this is the most straight-forward way to find out; via a 10px icon, instead of say a line on the overview section where the other high-level info resides. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the "Export Template" in the AppServicePlan overview page to view the ARM template for the AppServicePlan and check the "Kind" attribute.